TrueNas Scale sends nameserver request every few Seconds
For quite some time now I see a request from my TrueNas server every few seconds for a nameserver entry for the domain . in my PiHole and i cannot figure out why its doing that or what i did before that happends.
Any idea why TrueNas is doing that?
TrueNas Scale Cobia 23.10


Is the TrueNAS running its own DNS resolver (e.g. Unbound or similar)?

No not that i have configured it. PiHole runs on a VM on that TrueNas
